# Problems reverting to google maps API v1 on android

Tags: android, api, maps

I have an application which has been built on google maps api v1. I went to  upgrade to v2 so deleted my api key and created a new one.

I am sure that this is the debug key but still get the grey square on my application.

Is the original api still supported and if so is it possible to get an api key which will work with it or do the new keys only work with the v2 api?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the original api still supported

Yes.

> is it possible to get an api key which will work with it

For another couple of weeks, yes. Visit [the Maps V1 documentation for the instructions and form to get a Maps V1 API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/mapkey). This offer expires on March 3, 2013.

> or do the new keys only work with the v2 api?

They are entirely separate keys. A Maps V1 key will not work with Maps V2, and vice versa.